# Spread operator with bracket notation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The following works fine:

```
const o = {one:1,two:2,three:3};
const {one,...others}=o;//one=1, others={two:2,three:3}
```

But how would I do the following:

```
var o = {['this-is-one']:1,two:2,three:3};
var {['this-is-one'],...others}=o;
```

Currently that gives me a SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','

I suspect it would not work because `this-is-one` would be invalid for a constant name (it only works for property values).

Comment: give it an alias `{'this-is-one':one,...others}=o;`

Comment: `[]` is required only for computed property names. As mentioned in the above comment, it's not required while creating or destructuring an object

Comment: @adiga, it is necessary to pull out a property which does not comply for a variable name.

Comment: @NinaScholz I meant `[]` wrapper is not required. Just `var o = { 'this-is-one':1,two:2,three:3};
var {'this-is-one':one,...others}=o` is enough

Comment: @adiga, sorry you are right. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a renaming of the variable name, because the the given key is not a valid variable name.

```js
var o = { 'this-is-one': 1, two: 2, three: 3 },
    { 'this-is-one': thisIsOne, ...others } = o;

console.log(thisIsOne);
console.log(others);
```